# Register a service to eureka with preferred networks configuration not work

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I want to register a service to eureka, the server has two ip:

```
eth0: 192.168.121.74
eth1: 10.254.102.243
```

I want the service to be registered with ip 10.254.102.243, so my `appliction.yml` comes like this:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://10.254.102.12:1111/eureka/
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

spring:
  application:
    name: item-service
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  datasource:
    url: {url}
    username: {username}
    password: {password}
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      preferredNetworks:
        - 10.254
```

But this didn't work, the service still registered with ip 192.168.121.74.

When I run my the service like this:

```
java -Dspring.cloud.inetutils.preferredNetworks=10.254 -jar item-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

The service logs show the ip was `10.254.102.250` but actually ip was `127.0.0.1` which I found in the eureka server web page.

```
2017-07-09 15:44:06.658  INFO 24322 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ITEM-SERVICE/10.254.102.250:item-service: registering service...
2017-07-09 15:44:06.828  INFO 24322 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ITEM-SERVICE/10.254.102.250:item-service - registration status: 204
```

So how can I make the service registered with ip 10.254.102.243?

update:

When I move `preferredNetworks` into `bootstrap.yml`, it work like using `-Dspring.cloud.inetutils.preferredNetworks` in command line. In the eureka server web page the actual ip in the eureka web page still `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the following properties in `boostrap.yml` instead of `application.yml`. You can add addition interfaces that you want to ignore.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignoredInterfaces:
        - lo
        - lo*
        - eth0*
```

Comment: I thought `boostrap.yml ` was used for Spring Cloud Config. But this solved part of my problems.